# Russia attacks Ukraine. Why is world's reaction so slow?

Tags: armed-conflict, international-relations, russian-federation, nuclear-weapons, ukraine

Russia has occupied Crimea, and Russian soldiers are getting ready to attack Kharkiv this night.

About Crimea - this has been obvious for last few days. Just words. Russia don't do it, this is bad.

Kharkiv - this is new information but also obvious enough. Easy to check. Still no reaction.

Russia, Great Britain and USA promised to keep Ukrainian independence in case we give up our nuclear weapon. We did.

Now Ukrainian independence does not exist any more. Noone cares.

Dear countries who promissed Ukraine to help it if it will be in danger, you show other countries which have nuclear weapon that they should not give up. If you do not help Ukraine now, noone will abadon nuclear weapon himself in future.

Why noone cares?

Why is reaction so slow?

Comment: As an American, I sympathize with your cause 100%.  From my reading, the heroics in Kiev should be supported. At the risk of sounding hokey, you are in my prayers.  I understand your frustration. I am fearful that we are witnessing Prague in 1968 and Budapest in 1956.  Ya ne lublyou Roccua. Ya znaou sto Roccua plocha. But, here's the deal.  You are preaching to people who frankly can do nothing about this except complain.  I am with you, but I know not what I can do.

Comment: As far as a question goes, I'm afraid I'm having to see this as rhetorical.  Again, please believe me when I say it pains me to put it on hold, because I completely sympathize with what you are experiencing.  Your country is being torn apart.  But this isn't a question, it is a speech.

Comment: And we do questions here, not speeches.

Comment: I am also very interested in this situation and reaction of the whole world but have to agree its very hard to ask question about it, because it will become a discussion :( even though you may agree that Russia's actions are breaking many international treaties (one mentioned in question 1994 budapest memorandum) but Russia itself just says they have rights to protect Russian people in Ukraine... By no means I fully support Ukraine in this conflict.

Comment: @Affable Geek I would like to try to answer this, can you please unprotect it?

Comment: @AffableGeek while I'd tend to agree that this sounds a bit more like a speech than a question, I also think editing it into a proper question could be doable. I'd reopen, let Anixx add his answer, and see if anyone manages to edit this into something more appropriate : )

Comment: @AffableGeek "Ya ne lublyou Roccua. Ya znaou sto Roccua plocha." Translation: "I don't like Russia. I know that Russia is bad." Besides an emotional rant I see an ethics problem here and I don't think that such comments are acceptable in an international community, which has a motto of being constructive.

Comment: I disagree it's opinion based, although badly formed. There are objective reasons for 'nobody cares', that is the logistical aspects and the actual embarassing weakness of European military force. In the same time, the Russia can send as much troops as will be needed with an ease.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Same reason why everyone allowed Hitler to gobble up part of Czechoslovakia back in 1938.

**Nobody wants to start a war with Russia over this.**

The West bluffed.

Putin, accurately reading Obama, called their bluff.

For a more expanded treatment (leading to the same conclusion but from a bit more of an expert), see [Niall Ferguson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niall_Ferguson)'s article in Wall Street Journal called "[America's Global Retreat](http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB10001424052702303945704579391492993958448?mod=trending_now_2)"

Comment: I hate it that you are right.

Comment: I think you're right, but they want to use economic pressure like sanctions first to try to cause him to change his mind before any action is taken. The West could give a missile shield to Ukraine and ship in weapons to defend it against further incursions.

Comment: And I could box Klitchko.

Comment: I doubt there will be war with Russia if NATO sent troops on Ukraine. They wouldn't have to do that officially, but just the way the Russia is doing it. The problem is, European NATO members neighbouring Ukraine have weak land forces and Amis are far away, while Russia has full freedom to operate in that region.

Answer (score 6):

I don't really know if you're seeking justice, but in my humble opinion superpowers, be it the USA, Russia or european countries would never support a political movement if it weren't for their interests. Pleas for help made by less influential countries will certainly cost. At least that's what history has shown.

Be cautious: the loud voices from the West proclaiming independence will eventually reveal their true face. As seen in most african and middle-eastern countries, interventions to overthrow dictators, combat terrorism or whatever other pretext is advertised, has benefited only the participating western countries. This is not to exonerate Russia, which indeed presents an imperialistic approach and seeks profit as well.

However considering the current situation you should follow the lesser of two evils principle, unless you want to alienate your country. Whatever your choice make sure to negotiate extended demands and agreements **to your interest**. I trust you know best what is good for your country and urge you to strengthen it instead of hoping for a saviour.

Comment: Heh, isn't there interest lower corruption? The US is a much better choice. The US businessmen like free and open markets and a predictable judicial system. Russia is very corrupt. They would make it worse.

Comment: It's not only your interest, but your capabilities. If something is in your interest, but lies beyond your capabilities, you must abstain from it.